# Detecting invalid polygons (self-intersecting or touching)

Tags: c#, polygon, algorithm, intersection, mathematics

An invalid polygon can be defined as one that intersects itself, or one where the lines make contact, ie, the two shapes at the top of this picture.

[image: http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Straight_skeleton_2/invalid_polygons.png]

Given the XYPoints of a polygon, what logic (using C# preferably, but as long as I see logic, I can translate) could be implemented to detect these situations?

I've looked at the [Bentley-Ottmann_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley-Ottmann_algorithm), however this detects if lines intersect and not if they touch. Not to mention, it says in the wikipedia article that it's slow.

Comment: The Wikipedia article asserts the *opposite* of slow! Yes, there are improvements that assume special conditions on the polygons: see the [Faster Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley-Ottmann_algorithm#Faster_algorithms) section in the same Wikipedia article.

Comment: Which GIS system are you wishing to implement such code? If you are using ESRI software then the check geometry tool as suggested below is a good start. If you want to call existing ArcObjects then have a look at the ITopologicalOperator interface?

Comment: ArcGIS. However I'm writing a C# library that does this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the Hoey-Shamos algorithm. I'm in the middle of implementing (code works, but is too slow, I'm optimizing it)

I can't post my exact code since this is for a private organization, but I can post a link to the Java code I based my code off of

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-this-implementation-of-shamos-hoey-algorithm-ok

Line2D as mentioned in the above link, is a Java class. I created a C# version of that class. TreeSets are not available in C#, so I used a List, but I will have to find a way to optimize that, since I'm pretty sure that's where my bottleneck is. I can share the Line2D class, but that's it I'm afraid :(

```
public class Line2D
{
    public double X1 = 0;
    public double X2 = 0;
    public double Y1 = 0;
    public double Y2 = 0;

    public XYPoints P1;
    public XYPoints P2;

    public Line2D(XYPoints p1, XYPoints p2)
    {
        P1 = p1; 
        P2 = p2;
        X1 = p1.X;
        X2 = p2.X;
        Y1 = p1.Y;
        Y2 = p2.Y;
    }

    public double getX1()
    {
        return X1;
    }
    public double getX2()
    {
        return X2;
    }
    public double getY1()
    {
        return Y1;
    }
    public double getY2()
    {
        return Y2;
    }

    public XYPoints getP1()
    {
        return P1;
    }

    public XYPoints getP2()
    {
        return P2;
    }

    public bool intersectsLine(Line2D comparedLine)
    {
        if (X2 == comparedLine.X1 && Y2 == comparedLine.Y1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (X1 == comparedLine.X2 && Y1 == comparedLine.Y2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        double firstLineSlopeX, firstLineSlopeY, secondLineSlopeX, secondLineSlopeY;

        firstLineSlopeX = X2 - X1;
        firstLineSlopeY = Y2 - Y1;

        secondLineSlopeX = comparedLine.getX2() - comparedLine.getX1();
        secondLineSlopeY = comparedLine.getY2() - comparedLine.getY1();

        double s, t;
        s = (-firstLineSlopeY * (X1 - comparedLine.getX1()) + firstLineSlopeX * (getY1() - comparedLine.getY1())) / (-secondLineSlopeX * firstLineSlopeY + firstLineSlopeX * secondLineSlopeY);
        t = (secondLineSlopeX * (getY1() - comparedLine.getY1()) - secondLineSlopeY * (getX1() - comparedLine.getX1())) / (-secondLineSlopeX * firstLineSlopeY + firstLineSlopeX * secondLineSlopeY);

        if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false; // No collision
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (X1 * 1000 + X2 * 1000 + Y1 * 1000 + Y2 * 1000).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj.GetHashCode() == this.GetHashCode());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write something from scratch, you could possibly call Check Geometry from ArcToolbox. I've used it a few times for certain geometries. Not sure if all of the above cases will be returned as bad geometry. You may want to test the tool on a test dataset.